# Multiple PHP versions on the same box

Tags: php, server-configuration, multiple-versions

Is it possible to have multiple versions of PHP running on the same box ( like rails ) . Here is my problem , I need to start development on a new project and was planning to use PHP 5.3 for it so that I can use the latest Zend framework and active record with it . 
 However the machine where I need to host my application has PHP 4.4 and there are several other applications hosted there . I do not want to upgrade the PHP version on the server as in the past I have faced a lot of issues while upgrading the PHP version and deprecated functions . 
I was wondering if it is possible to have multiple version of PHP on the same box and then somehow specify the version that you want your application to load ( similar to rails )

Comment: Seems like this is a question for server fault...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, many servers operate this way. You may see .php4 and .php5 extensions from time to time indicating which version that particular script should be handled with.

ServerFault addressed this question

[Running php4 and php5 along side each other](https://serverfault.com/q/85385/running-php4-and-php5-al)

Answer (score 3):

You can run multiple PHP versions on the same box using Docker.

An example command would be:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8055:80 -v /var/www:/var/www \
  -v /etc/apache2/sites-available:/etc/apache2/sites-available \
  -v /etc/apache2/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled \
  codeyourdream/apache-sendmail-php55
```

Here's what this command does:

- It forwards your local `/var/www`, `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` to the corresponding folders of Docker container. If your local websites and/or apache configs are located in different folders, replace the first part of `-v` value.
  I.e. the format is:

  `docker run -v /host/directory:/container/directory -other -options image_name command_to_run`
- It forwards port 8055 of your local machine to port 80 of Docker container
- It runs the container from "codeyourdream/apache-sendmail-php55" image

If you run this command, all your local websites should be available via port 8055 (i.e. via URLs like http://localsite:8055) and processed by PHP 5.5

See https://codeyourdream.com/blog/how-run-multiple-php-versions-apache-one-linux-machine-using-docker for more details.
Affiliation note: this is my team's blog.

Answer (score 0):

A possiblity is using one version of PHP as an Apache module, and the other version as a CGI ; but an idea I kind of like better is to have :

- Several distinct instances of Apache,
- Each one listening on a different port *(for instance, PHP 4.4 on port 44000, and PHP 5.3.1 on port 53100)*
- And each one using a different version of PHP

This way, you have totally different environments, that works independantly of each other, and you can configure/modify anything you want in each environment without risking breaking any of the others.

*(And if you don't want to have port numbers in your URLs, I suppose you can put a proxy in front of your distinct Apache instances, so it seems there is only one)*