# Installing multiple PHP versions on Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

**Initial Situation:**

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 Server hosting 3 Websites (with Apache 2.2.22)

How can I install a different PHP version for only one of the Websites?
(The other 2 should remain as they are)

Current PHP Version: PHP 5.3.10
Desired PHP Version: PHP 5.6.16

**What i have done/understood until now:**

I have already tried out PHPBrew:
http://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/

I managed to install PHP 5.6.16 for the command line (with PHPBrew) but the Apache still uses PHP 5.3.10.

I understood that i should end up with an *.so file which i need to place in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file. (this file is empty at the moment)
(via LoadModule...)

**But:** I don't have any *.so files.
I installed PHPBrew like this:

phpbrew install 5.6.16 +default +mysql +mcrypt

I think I should have added +apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 but if I do this i get the error "Exception: apxs binary is not executable: /usr/bin/apxs2".

How can i fix this?

Or is there a better way to run different PHP versions on one Server?
What is the best way?

Comment: In order to fix "apxs binary is not executable" i managed to execute sudo apt-get install apache2-dev. I now have the php5.6.16.so file (after re-installing with +apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2). In etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load is the new php5.6.16.so file and after a restart of apache2 it worked. Last question remaining is: Is it possible to create a php5.load file for every vhost?

Comment: When I try, I get this one: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-dev : Depends: libapr1-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: IT seems that that package is not available anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have .so files? Have you checked /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Double check the `.so` files, they should be in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/``

Then you should edit your `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load` and specify the `.so` file that corresponds to your installation, in your case:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.6.16.so
```

An alternative solution for running multiple PHP versions on the same box is using Docker, see my answer in another thread: [Multiple PHP versions on the same box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905548/multiple-php-versions-on-the-same-box)

Note that with this solution different PHP versions will be available on different ports.