# How to Use Two Different PHP Versions on One Server

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I have 2 websites on a single server, but one site's PHP version must be 5.2.17,
 and the other must be 5.5+.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with Apache2 and PHP.

I have already installed PHP 5.5 (via `apt-get`) and 5.2.17 (via installation from source). Can somebody tell me how to configure and use different PHP versions for each specified website? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using **PHP version manager** and there are so many available, explore these:

- https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version
- https://github.com/CHH/phpenv
- https://github.com/c9s/phpbrew

Comment: 1:can't manage exist version 2:ing  3:can't install curl have some Alien code... so is there have other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple PHP versions on one server using Docker, see my answer in another thread: [Multiple PHP versions on the same box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905548/multiple-php-versions-on-the-same-box)

Note that with this solution different PHP versions will be available on different ports.