# Error installing Phalcon PHP: PHP 5.3 is no longer supported

Tags: php, ubuntu, phalcon

I tried to install Phalcon PHP but I got an error

```
php 5.3 is no longer supported
```

I check PHP Version

```
$ php -v
```

return

```
PHP 7.0.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2017 13:43:45) ( NTS )
```

but I check in phpinfo();

```
PHP Version 5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

Comment: well 5.3 still isn't 5.6. But sounds like maybe you've got two or more versions of PHP on your server. Ask the server administrator if you're not sure

Comment: Use a php version manager like one mentioned in here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505989/how-to-use-two-different-php-versions-on-one-server

Answer (score -1):

Phpinfo() will always show the version your server is currently running. You will need to change the php version that apache is using. You can do this by disabling PHP 5 module by checking your apcahe files or disabling with 'sudo a2dismod php5'. Then you will need to enable php 7 by allocating in your files or again enabling it with 'sudo a2enmod php7.1'. To see results you will need to restart apache. I hope this helps

Comment: oh oke . I'll try it first

Comment: I tried "sudo a2dismod php5" but result this                      sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
ERROR: Module php7.1 does not exist!

Comment: ah i see sorry misinterpreted your original question, may i suggest visiting, https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/14843/phalconphp-install-error-help-me. This may have your answer